What clusters & commands are required by the ZCL/Zigbee specification?
I've been trying to understand the Zigbee specification. I know there are many types of "clusters" of commands (see the full Zigbee Cluster Library specification), but I'm not certain which (if any) are mandatory.
What commands are all Zigbee devices required to support? For example, are all devices required to support the "group" cluster?
EDIT: I also note that Matter defines device types in the Matter Device Library, which explicitly delineate which clusters are required for different types of devices. For example, a dimmable light must support groups, on/off, and level control, among other things. Does such a thing exist for Zigbee?

Yes, there seem to be mandatory clusters for all Zigbee-certified devices (at least 3.0).

For Zigbee 3.0 certification, devices must implement the Base Device Behavior specification & at least one "application device specification" (p. 22):

The Product implementation SHALL conform to these Standard specifications as appropriate to the declared PICS:

[...]
Base Device Behavior specification
[...]
One or more application device specifications


There are a few application device specifications. A notable one is the ZigBee Lighting & Occupancy Device Specification, which describes several device types, like "On/off light", "Dimmable light", and "Color dimmable light", etc.
Each of these device types has a set of required & optional clusters.
Officially certified devices should have this tested
This is supposed to be tested for Zigbee certification (p. 6):

zigbee certified
products have had their underlying platforms, Base Device Behavior and application level
objects (from the ZCL) tested and validated to conform to the requirements of the various
standard documents. Products carrying the zigbee certified product mark carry with them the
confidence that all required behaviors (along with any implemented optional behavior) have
been properly vetted and thus can interoperate with other products carrying the same mark.

Example: on/off lights
For example, for On/Off lights (device ID 0x0100 & the standard profile Zigbee Home Automation profile ID, 0x0104):


Mandatory Server clusters

0x0000: Basic
0x0003: Identify
0x0004: Groups
0x0005: Scenes
0x0006: On/off


Recommended optional Server clusters

0x0008: Level control
0x1000: Touchlink commissioning


Recommended optional Client clusters

0x0019: OTA upgrade
0x0406: Occupancy sensing




See also

Silicon Labs' good overview of Zigbee endpoints, clusters, & device types

